# Access docker /var/jenkins_home from my mac

Tags: jenkins, docker

I have just started using Docker into Mac.

I have install first docker container called Jenkins. The Jenkins default home directory is:

```
/var/jenkins_home
```

How can I access this location from my mac?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
my-MacBook-Pro-2:$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                       NAMES
c28eee5c9f45        jenkins             "/bin/tini -- /usr/lo"   3 days ago          Up 3 days           0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 50000/tcp   silly_pare
```

Now you can access your container with `docker exec` and the container ID (if you did not specify a container name)

```
my-MacBook-Pro-2:$ docker exec -it c28eee5c9f45 bash
jenkins@c28eee5c9f45:~$ echo $JENKINS_HOME
/var/jenkins_home
jenkins@c28eee5c9f45:/$ cd /var/jenkins_home/
jenkins@c28eee5c9f45:~$ pwd
/var/jenkins_home
jenkins@c28eee5c9f45:~$ ls
config.xml               hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml  init.groovy.d                        jobs  nodeMonitors.xml  plugins     secret.key.not-so-secret  updates      users
copy_reference_file.log  identity.key.enc               jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state  logs  nodes             secret.key  secrets                   userContent  war
```

You can leave your container with `exit`

Answer (score 1):

Run the image in interactive mode, with `bash` as the entry point.

```
docker run -it --name=bash_jenkins <jenkins_image_name> /bin/bash
```

This will start an interactive bash session.
Post that you can just `cd` to the required location :

```
cd /var/jenkins_home
```